# Can my network be too fast for my network card?

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

Recently upgraded my home internet to fiber optic from cable. Everything's fast, even with multiple devices pulling data at the same time.

But my Windows 10 desktop computer will, five or six times randomly each day, lose network connectivity. Using the troubleshooter always results in the (wired) ethernet adapter being reset after 30 seconds or so, which restores connectivity. Every other device is wireless and they do not exhibit this behavior.

Microsoft assures me I have the latest driver for my adapter, but it's dated 2013. Am I just trying to shove too much data at an outdated piece of hardware, or am I overlooking a setting that will make things stable again?

- Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
- Driver version 2.1.0.16, April 1 2013
- Altice 1 Gig service from Optimum Because of where the fiber had to come into the house, and the distance I'd have to run cable, the desktop is actually connected to   a wifi repeater about 1 meter away

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely.

Network devices talk with each other and mutually agree on a link speed before the connection is established. Any modern switch/router is capable of setting link speeds for each port individually, and there's no direct link between the uplink/WAN side of a home router and the LAN side. Your computer isn't "drowning" in front of a fire hose.

Try an inexpensive alternate NIC in this computer and see if the issues continue. If they do not, the problem is with that specific NIC. If they do the issue is more likely with the computer.